# No audio with peerjs (no errors)?

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, peerjs

I'm trying to add audio chat to a game using WebRTC via [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/). I am successfully generating a unique ID for both peers, then passing these through a socket.io server and establishing a call. Once each client has each other's audio stream, I'm attaching this to a new `<audio>` tag and appending it to the body. **But there is no audible sound once the connection is made.**

My code is as follows:

**Creating peers, unique ids:**

```js
import Peer from 'peerjs';
import getUserMedia from 'getusermedia';

// ...

getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }, (err, stream) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  console.log('Got audio stream!');

  this.peer = new Peer();
  
  this.peer.on('open', (id) => {
    this.p2pAddress = id;
    this.audioStream = stream;
    joinBtn.setInteractive();
    joinBtn.setAlpha(1);
  });
});
```

Note this is all within a [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/) game, so I'm assigning the `p2pAddress` and `audioStream` to the current scene, then passing them into the subsequent scene when the user clicks the join button (I've console logged them in the next scene though, and they are indeed being passed through).

**Listening for incoming calls:**

```js
// Audio chat
this.peer.on('call', (call) => {
  call.answer(this.audioStream);
  console.log('Answered incoming call');

  call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
    console.log('Got stream', remoteStream);
    const audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(audio);

    audio.srcObject = remoteStream;
    audio.play();
  });
});
```

**Initiating an audio stream:**

```js
// Initate audio stream
const call = this.peer.call(player.p2pAddress, this.audioStream);
console.log('Calling', player.p2pAddress);
console.log(this.audioStream);

call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
  const audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(audio);

  audio.srcObject = remoteStream;
  audio.play();
});
```

In this case, `player.p2pAddress` represents the id of the other peer. Again, I've console logged this and it is being transferred through no problem.

So what's actually happening is as follows:

1. The first player spawns, and the world is empty.
2. The second player spawns, entering the world instance of the first player.
3. The first player receives the second player's `p2pAddress` and initiates a call with their `audioStream`.
4. The second player answers the call with their `audioStream`.

The console logs in the above code are firing off as if it's working, but I don't hear anything on either client device.

Things I've tried:

- Attaching the player's own `audioStream` to an `<audio>` element on their own device, to verify that the stream is working. I heard feedback and sound, so the audio stream is good.
- Console logged the incoming stream and it is indeed an instance of `MediaStream`.
- Tried both `audio.play()` and `audio.autoplay = true` on the `<audio>` element.
- Verified the `<audio> element was being attached to the` ` with the inspector.
- Tested it locally, as well as on a server with `https://`.
- Made sure permissions were granted for both devices.
- Made sure the volume was up on both devices.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

NVM IT WORKS!

I was testing an old version on the `https://` server, when I pushed the updates it works on the remote server. I guess it just doesn't work on localhost.